# How to get dynamically changing value from external url in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, get

I'm trying to get a quantity value from external link, but I can't see this value until particular colour or size is selected (selection on that website works using JavaScript void(0) ).

Is it possible to trigger a link somehow and get the value after? Any suggestions?

However I know how to get a static value from url, see below:

```html
$url = 'http://www.website.com/page.html';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<span id="quantity">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</span>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
```

Comment: You would need to use a headless browser to do it

Comment: @charlietfl could you explain this in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe solution, you can to split the process into two parts :

get all elements with regexp

```
preg_match_all('/<span [^>]+>/i',$content , $match); 
print_r($match);
```

search attrs array of the result

```
$spans = array();
foreach( $match as $tag)
{
    preg_match_all('/(id)=("[^"]*")/i',$tag, $spans[$tag]);
}

print_r($spans);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Claudionor but I need something to select colour first in order to get the right quantity of items. Probably I would click colour box on my website and it should trigger the external link, so I could get the updated value from span tag. :) any ideas?